# Performance issue regarding loading large gifs into UIViews quickly

Tags: ios, image, performance, uiimageview, gif

Wondering if has an idea to a performance problem in an app I'm working on:

Basically the app is tinder for gifs, so I scrape gifs from r/gifs on reddit and load them into a modified MDCSwipeToChooseView (https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose).

The basis of the problem is the size of the gifs, which are all around 4-6 MB in size, so when I load the gif's url in an imageView with https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage, it takes a full 5-10 seconds.

```
FLAnimatedImage *gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.gif.gifLink]]];
```

The result is 1. gifs load extremely slowly, especially on first launch (as gifs are being shown, I pull and load subsequent gifViews to be shown later in background) 2. app uses a ton of cellular data
I guess there isn't a way around the cellular data issue as the gifs are just large, but I'm looking to make the gifs load faster. Maybe downloading and recycling the actual gifs (in background) and loading them from a local path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be loading the animated GIF asynchronously then setting it on the view, like so.

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:nil/*your URL*/ completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    FLAnimatedImage *gifImage = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        animatedImageView.image = gifImage;
    });
}] resume];
```